# swift why is characters.split used for? and why is map(String.init) used for

Tags: swift, swift3

```
import Foundation

for i in 1 ... n {

    let entry = readLine()!.characters.split(" ").map(String.init)

    let name = entry[0]

    let phone = Int(entry[1])!


    phoneBook[name] = phone``

}
```

//can someone explain this piece of code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you know everything else in the code except this line:

```
let entry = readLine()!.characters.split(" ").map(String.init)
```

`readLine()` reads user input and returns it. Let's say the user input is

```
Sweeper 12345678
```

using `.characters.split(" ")`, we split the input using a separator. What is this separator? A space (" ")! Now the input has been split into two - "Sweeper" and "12345678".

We want the two split parts to be strings, right? Strings are much more easier to manipulate. Currently the split parts are stored in an array of `String.CharacterView.SubSequence`. We want to turn each `String.CharacterView.SubSequence` into a string. That is why we use `map`. `map` applies a certain function to everything in a collection. So

```
.map(String.init)
```

is like

```
// this is for demonstration purposes only, not real code
for x in readLine()!.characters.split(" ") {
    String.init(x)
}
```

We have now transformed the whole collection into strings!

Answer (score 0):

There is error in your code replace it like below:

```
let entry = readLine()!.characters.split(separator: " ").map(String.init)
```

Alternative to the above code is:

```
let entry = readLine()!.components(separatedBy: " ")
```

Example:

```
var str = "Hello, playground"

let entry = str.characters.split(separator: " ").map(String.init)
print(entry)
```

Now `characters.split` with split the characters with the separator you give in above case " "(space). So it will generate an array of characters. And you need to use it as string so you are mapping characters into `String` type by `map()`.